# wp_redirect is not working on functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a scenario that if any user that is created manually by adding in wp_users table in database(In case of importing csv of users in db)and if that user visits my site then he will be redirected to welcome page.
Forexample [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is my site domain.If users visits this site then they will re-directed to [www.example.com/welcome/](http://www.example.com/welcome/)
For this purpose i have used this following code in functions.php file.

```
function redirectUser(){
wp_redirect(home_url('/welcome/'));
exit;

}
add_action('init','redirectUser');
```

But when i refresh my home page,Page goes die.So what i am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciable

Comment: Looks like an endless loop. Your site redirect all requests, regardless whether welcome page or not.

Comment: why not with `htaccess`
**`Redirect 301 http://www.example.com/ http://www.example.com/welcome`**

Comment: @Noman.Actually i want this for some specific users.So i cant do this with htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

run it code without add actions

```
wp_redirect(home_url('/welcome/'));

// OR

function redirectUser($url){
    wp_redirect(home_url($url));
    exit;
}

redirectUser(home_url('/welcome/'));
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed.I have done this with following code.I think by adding If conditions i able to solve my issue.Code is here.function redirectUserOnFirstVisit(){
 //ob_start();
 $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
 $link=explode('/',$actual_link);
 if(is_user_logged_in()){
$user_id=get_current_user_id();
 $last_login=get_option('lastlogin-'.$user_id);
  if(empty($last_login)|| $last_login==''){
  if($link[3]!='welcome-eq-org')
 {
  
    wp_redirect(home_url('/welcome-eq-org/'));
     exit();
 }
  
  
  }}
 }